# prevent changing the read only status of an excel document

Tags: excel

I know you can make an excel and other office files read only by going into right click properties in windows and clicking read only.

However is there anyway to prevent someone from downloading the file and simply right clicking and un checking the read only box?

This is a very important file and I don't want someone to be able to uncheck the read only box  on an excel document!

Thanks,

Josh.

Comment: are you talking about the file properties or the built-in (which you can password protect) read-only?

Comment: I was talking about using the windows properties dialog box - but it seems anyone could just save a file like that in a new folder, and the read only status would be removed.

Are there other ways to make the document read only? I tried protecting the workbook, do I have to lock the cells for that to work?

Happy to hear about other ways to make the document read only

Comment: Files downloaded over the internet don't share the "read-only" property, so that won't work, you can use Excel's built-in protection against modification - take into account that its NOT 100% secure

Comment: but do you have to lock cells for that built in protection to work?